Why is Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 significantly slower on Raspberry Pi 5 than Ubuntu 22.04 on Raspberry Pi 4?
I have set up two separate systems for comparison: a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 and a Raspberry Pi 5 running Ubuntu Desktop 24.04. I've noticed significant performance differences; applications like Nautilus and gnome-terminal take about 30 seconds to launch on the Raspberry Pi 5, and even routine tasks in LibreOffice and Firefox are noticeably slower compared to the Raspberry Pi 4 where these applications run much smoother and faster.
Is there a known issue with Ubuntu 24.04 on Raspberry Pi 5? What could be causing this performance degradation? Are there specific settings or updates that I should look into to improve performance on the Raspberry Pi 5? Any insights or experiences with similar issues would be greatly appreciated.
I have closely managed the software configurations on my devices. On my Raspberry Pi 4b, I removed all SNAP packages and switched to using DEB-based software like Chromium. This adjustment made applications like Chromium and Rhythmbox work instantly, matching the performance on my RPi4. I applied the same software configuration to the Raspberry Pi 5. While applications like Chromium perform well, the RPi5 is still significantly slower overall compared to the RPi4.
Interestingly, one of the slowest applications on the RPi5 is the gnome-terminal en Nautilus, which is unusually slow—almost comically so. Additionally, I have updated the firmware on the RPi5 and tried various operating systems. Despite these changes, all setups involving Ubuntu variants continue to perform poorly.

Operating systems like Android do not exhibit any such performance issues, which suggests that the problem might be more related to the specific Ubuntu setup than to the hardware itself. It seems like blaming the hardware alone is too simplistic, and I suspect a combination of factors at play here.

Maybe. 24.04 had its issues as it was delayed so that could be an indicator too. FF on my system is so meh I am considering switching :P My comment is an assumption so I'll remove it ;)

If enough users send in bug reports about the poor performance of Ubuntu 24.04 on Raspberry Pi 5 the issue will receive attention and the poor performance will improve.

I am having similar experiences - 24.04 is significantly slower than 22.04 on the same machine. OpenGL applications run slower and overall startup time is larger than on 22.04. There seems to be something wrong with the latest LTS. Also did I mention it is not as stable? It logged me out a few times without any reason, and sometimes it fails to start a pinned application at all (teminal). 24.04 seems not stable at this point. Looking forward to some updates there that will fix those issues.

I am running Ubuntu 24.04 on a RPi 5 4Gb RAM.
I have no problems running any applications such as LibreOffice or Gnome-Terminal.
LibreOffice loads in less than 5 seconds, Gnome-Terminal in less than 1 second.
However...
I run my RPi 5 from either a good quality (Samsung T-series, Seagate or Western Digital) SSD or a high speed SD Card like a Sandisk Extreme or Samsung EVO Plus.
If you try to run from a standard Sandisk Ultra 16Gb SD card or Sandisk Ultra 32Gb Flash drive, it will be so slow as to drive you to distraction.
Your RPi 5 can read and write at up to 400 MBytes/sec via USB 3 or 80 Mbytes/sec from the SD slot, if you use a good enough drive or card.
Also, don't forget to run all your updates!!!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
